# Segmentation Fault: Running nvidia deepstream 5.0 SDK on Ubuntu

Tags: nvidia-deepstream

Trying to run nvidia’s deepstream5.0 sdk (sample program) on ubuntu 18.04 by following the document (DeepStream Development Guide — DeepStream DeepStream Version: 5.0 documentation).

- Hardware Platform (Jetson / GPU)=GPU NVIDIA GEFORCE RTX 2060
- TensorRT Version=7.0
- NVIDIA GPU Driver Version (valid for GPU only):450.102
- Issue Type( questions, new requirements, bugs)=bugs
- GCC=7.5
- PYTHON 3.7
- CUDNN 7.6.5
- CUDA 10.2

The application is installed in the path: “/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/”.

The execution command is "deepstream-app -c "

Example:

```
deepstream-app -c /opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/samples/configs/deepstream-app/source30_1080p_dec_infer-resnet_tiled_display_int8.txt
```

However got segmentation fault just after opening a blank screen and closing suddenly

```
ERROR: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_model_builder.cpp:1523 Deserialize engine failed because file path: /opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/samples/configs/deepstream-app/…/…/models/Secondary_CarMake/resnet18.caffemodel_b16_gpu0_int8.engine open error
0:00:01.788894483 9829 0x5594636fc490 WARN nvinfer gstnvinfer.cpp:616:gst_nvinfer_logger:<secondary_gie_2> NvDsInferContext[UID 6]: Warning from NvDsInferContextImpl::deserializeEngineAndBackend() <nvdsinfer_context_impl.cpp:1690> [UID = 6]: deserialize engine from file :/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/samples/configs/deepstream-app/…/…/models/Secondary_CarMake/resnet18.caffemodel_b16_gpu0_int8.engine failed
0:00:01.788911328 9829 0x5594636fc490 WARN nvinfer gstnvinfer.cpp:616:gst_nvinfer_logger:<secondary_gie_2> NvDsInferContext[UID 6]: Warning from NvDsInferContextImpl::generateBackendContext() <nvdsinfer_context_impl.cpp:1797> [UID = 6]: deserialize backend context from engine from file :/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/samples/configs/deepstream-app/…/…/models/Secondary_CarMake/resnet18.caffemodel_b16_gpu0_int8.engine failed, try rebuild
0:00:01.788917862 9829 0x5594636fc490 INFO nvinfer gstnvinfer.cpp:619:gst_nvinfer_logger:<secondary_gie_2> NvDsInferContext[UID 6]: Info from NvDsInferContextImpl::buildModel() <nvdsinfer_context_impl.cpp:1715> [UID = 6]: Trying to create engine from model files
Warning: Flatten layer ignored. TensorRT implicitly flattens input to FullyConnected layers, but in other circumstances this will result in undefined behavior.
INFO: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_func_utils.cpp:39 [TRT]: Reading Calibration Cache for calibrator: EntropyCalibration2
INFO: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_func_utils.cpp:39 [TRT]: Generated calibration scales using calibration cache. Make sure that calibration cache has latest scales.
INFO: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_func_utils.cpp:39 [TRT]: To regenerate calibration cache, please delete the existing one. TensorRT will generate a new calibration cache.
INFO: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_func_utils.cpp:39 [TRT]: Some tactics do not have sufficient workspace memory to run. Increasing workspace size may increase performance, please check verbose output.
INFO: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_func_utils.cpp:39 [TRT]: Detected 1 inputs and 1 output network tensors.
ERROR: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_model_builder.cpp:1495 Serialize engine failed because of file path: /opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/samples/models/Secondary_CarMake/resnet18.caffemodel_b16_gpu0_int8.engine opened error
0:00:11.045161759 9829 0x5594636fc490 WARN nvinfer gstnvinfer.cpp:616:gst_nvinfer_logger:<secondary_gie_2> NvDsInferContext[UID 6]: Warning from NvDsInferContextImpl::buildModel() <nvdsinfer_context_impl.cpp:1743> [UID = 6]: failed to serialize cude engine to file: /opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/samples/models/Secondary_CarMake/resnet18.caffemodel_b16_gpu0_int8.engine
WARNING: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_func_utils.cpp:36 [TRT]: Current optimization profile is: 0. Please ensure there are no enqueued operations pending in this context prior to switching profiles
INFO: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_model_builder.cpp:685 [Implicit Engine Info]: layers num: 2
0 INPUT kFLOAT input_1 3x224x224
1 OUTPUT kFLOAT predictions/Softmax 20x1x1
```

```
0:00:11.054222978 9829 0x5594636fc490 INFO nvinfer gstnvinfer_impl.cpp:313:notifyLoadModelStatus:<secondary_gie_2> [UID 6]: Load new model:/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/samples/configs/deepstream-app/config_infer_secondary_carmake.txt sucessfully
ERROR: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_model_builder.cpp:1523 Deserialize engine failed because file path: /opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/samples/configs/deepstream-app/…/…/models/Secondary_CarColor/resnet18.caffemodel_b16_gpu0_int8.engine open error
```

```
0:00:11.054352982 9829 0x5594636fc490 WARN nvinfer gstnvinfer.cpp:616:gst_nvinfer_logger:<secondary_gie_1> NvDsInferContext[UID 5]: Warning from NvDsInferContextImpl::deserializeEngineAndBackend() <nvdsinfer_context_impl.cpp:1690> [UID = 5]: deserialize engine from file :/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/samples/configs/deepstream-app/…/…/models/Secondary_CarColor/resnet18.caffemodel_b16_gpu0_int8.engine failed
0:00:11.054360902 9829 0x5594636fc490 WARN nvinfer gstnvinfer.cpp:616:gst_nvinfer_logger:<secondary_gie_1> NvDsInferContext[UID 5]: Warning from NvDsInferContextImpl::generateBackendContext() <nvdsinfer_context_impl.cpp:1797> [UID = 5]: deserialize backend context from engine from file :/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/samples/configs/deepstream-app/…/…/models/Secondary_CarColor/resnet18.caffemodel_b16_gpu0_int8.engine failed, try rebuild
```

```
0:00:11.054365641 9829 0x5594636fc490 INFO nvinfer gstnvinfer.cpp:619:gst_nvinfer_logger:<secondary_gie_1> NvDsInferContext[UID 5]: Info from NvDsInferContextImpl::buildModel() <nvdsinfer_context_impl.cpp:1715> [UID = 5]: Trying to create engine from model files
Warning: Flatten layer ignored. TensorRT implicitly flattens input to FullyConnected layers, but in other circumstances this will result in undefined behavior.
INFO: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_func_utils.cpp:39 [TRT]: Reading Calibration Cache for calibrator: EntropyCalibration2
INFO: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_func_utils.cpp:39 [TRT]: Generated calibration scales using calibration cache. Make sure that calibration cache has latest scales.
INFO: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_func_utils.cpp:39 [TRT]: To regenerate calibration cache, please delete the existing one. TensorRT will generate a new calibration cache.
INFO: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_func_utils.cpp:39 [TRT]: Some tactics do not have sufficient workspace memory to run. Increasing workspace size may increase performance, please check verbose output.
INFO: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_func_utils.cpp:39 [TRT]: Detected 1 inputs and 1 output network tensors.
ERROR: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_model_builder.cpp:1495 Serialize engine failed because of file path: /opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/samples/models/Secondary_CarColor/resnet18.caffemodel_b16_gpu0_int8.engine opened error
0:00:19.492522201 9829 0x5594636fc490 WARN nvinfer gstnvinfer.cpp:616:gst_nvinfer_logger:<secondary_gie_1> NvDsInferContext[UID 5]: Warning from NvDsInferContextImpl::buildModel() <nvdsinfer_context_impl.cpp:1743> [UID = 5]: failed to serialize cude engine to file: /opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/samples/models/Secondary_CarColor/resnet18.caffemodel_b16_gpu0_int8.engine
WARNING: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_func_utils.cpp:36 [TRT]: Current optimization profile is: 0. Please ensure there are no enqueued operations pending in this context prior to switching profiles
INFO: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_model_builder.cpp:685 [Implicit Engine Info]: layers num: 2
0 INPUT kFLOAT input_1 3x224x224
1 OUTPUT kFLOAT predictions/Softmax 12x1x1
```

```
0:00:19.497783953 9829 0x5594636fc490 INFO nvinfer gstnvinfer_impl.cpp:313:notifyLoadModelStatus:<secondary_gie_1> [UID 5]: Load new model:/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/samples/configs/deepstream-app/config_infer_secondary_carcolor.txt sucessfully
ERROR: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_model_builder.cpp:1523 Deserialize engine failed because file path: /opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/samples/configs/deepstream-app/…/…/models/Secondary_VehicleTypes/resnet18.caffemodel_b16_gpu0_int8.engine open error
0:00:19.497944601 9829 0x5594636fc490 WARN nvinfer gstnvinfer.cpp:616:gst_nvinfer_logger:<secondary_gie_0> NvDsInferContext[UID 4]: Warning from NvDsInferContextImpl::deserializeEngineAndBackend() <nvdsinfer_context_impl.cpp:1690> [UID = 4]: deserialize engine from file :/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/samples/configs/deepstream-app/…/…/models/Secondary_VehicleTypes/resnet18.caffemodel_b16_gpu0_int8.engine failed
0:00:19.497954066 9829 0x5594636fc490 WARN nvinfer gstnvinfer.cpp:616:gst_nvinfer_logger:<secondary_gie_0> NvDsInferContext[UID 4]: Warning from NvDsInferContextImpl::generateBackendContext() <nvdsinfer_context_impl.cpp:1797> [UID = 4]: deserialize backend context from engine from file :/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/samples/configs/deepstream-app/…/…/models/Secondary_VehicleTypes/resnet18.caffemodel_b16_gpu0_int8.engine failed, try rebuild
0:00:19.497959157 9829 0x5594636fc490 INFO nvinfer gstnvinfer.cpp:619:gst_nvinfer_logger:<secondary_gie_0> NvDsInferContext[UID 4]: Info from NvDsInferContextImpl::buildModel() <nvdsinfer_context_impl.cpp:1715> [UID = 4]: Trying to create engine from model files
Warning: Flatten layer ignored. TensorRT implicitly flattens input to FullyConnected layers, but in other circumstances this will result in undefined behavior.
INFO: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_func_utils.cpp:39 [TRT]: Reading Calibration Cache for calibrator: EntropyCalibration2
INFO: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_func_utils.cpp:39 [TRT]: Generated calibration scales using calibration cache. Make sure that calibration cache has latest scales.
INFO: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_func_utils.cpp:39 [TRT]: To regenerate calibration cache, please delete the existing one. TensorRT will generate a new calibration cache.
INFO: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_func_utils.cpp:39 [TRT]: Some tactics do not have sufficient workspace memory to run. Increasing workspace size may increase performance, please check verbose output.
INFO: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_func_utils.cpp:39 [TRT]: Detected 1 inputs and 1 output network tensors.
ERROR: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_model_builder.cpp:1495 Serialize engine failed because of file path: /opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/samples/models/Secondary_VehicleTypes/resnet18.caffemodel_b16_gpu0_int8.engine opened error
0:00:27.394531547 9829 0x5594636fc490 WARN nvinfer gstnvinfer.cpp:616:gst_nvinfer_logger:<secondary_gie_0> NvDsInferContext[UID 4]: Warning from NvDsInferContextImpl::buildModel() <nvdsinfer_context_impl.cpp:1743> [UID = 4]: failed to serialize cude engine to file: /opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/samples/models/Secondary_VehicleTypes/resnet18.caffemodel_b16_gpu0_int8.engine
WARNING: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_func_utils.cpp:36 [TRT]: Current optimization profile is: 0. Please ensure there are no enqueued operations pending in this context prior to switching profiles
INFO: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_model_builder.cpp:685 [Implicit Engine Info]: layers num: 2
0 INPUT kFLOAT input_1 3x224x224
1 OUTPUT kFLOAT predictions/Softmax 6x1x1
```

```
0:00:27.401846636 9829 0x5594636fc490 INFO nvinfer gstnvinfer_impl.cpp:313:notifyLoadModelStatus:<secondary_gie_0> [UID 4]: Load new model:/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/samples/configs/deepstream-app/config_infer_secondary_vehicletypes.txt sucessfully
gstnvtracker: Loading low-level lib at /opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/lib/libnvds_mot_klt.so
gstnvtracker: Optional NvMOT_RemoveStreams not implemented
gstnvtracker: Batch processing is OFF
gstnvtracker: Past frame output is OFF
ERROR: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_model_builder.cpp:1523 Deserialize engine failed because file path: /opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/samples/configs/deepstream-app/…/…/models/Primary_Detector/resnet10.caffemodel_b4_gpu0_int8.engine open error
0:00:27.405130601 9829 0x5594636fc490 WARN nvinfer gstnvinfer.cpp:616:gst_nvinfer_logger:<primary_gie> NvDsInferContext[UID 1]: Warning from NvDsInferContextImpl::deserializeEngineAndBackend() <nvdsinfer_context_impl.cpp:1690> [UID = 1]: deserialize engine from file :/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/samples/configs/deepstream-app/…/…/models/Primary_Detector/resnet10.caffemodel_b4_gpu0_int8.engine failed
0:00:27.405139410 9829 0x5594636fc490 WARN nvinfer gstnvinfer.cpp:616:gst_nvinfer_logger:<primary_gie> NvDsInferContext[UID 1]: Warning from NvDsInferContextImpl::generateBackendContext() <nvdsinfer_context_impl.cpp:1797> [UID = 1]: deserialize backend context from engine from file :/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/samples/configs/deepstream-app/…/…/models/Primary_Detector/resnet10.caffemodel_b4_gpu0_int8.engine failed, try rebuild
0:00:27.405144384 9829 0x5594636fc490 INFO nvinfer gstnvinfer.cpp:619:gst_nvinfer_logger:<primary_gie> NvDsInferContext[UID 1]: Info from NvDsInferContextImpl::buildModel() <nvdsinfer_context_impl.cpp:1715> [UID = 1]: Trying to create engine from model files
INFO: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_func_utils.cpp:39 [TRT]: Reading Calibration Cache for calibrator: EntropyCalibration2
INFO: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_func_utils.cpp:39 [TRT]: Generated calibration scales using calibration cache. Make sure that calibration cache has latest scales.
INFO: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_func_utils.cpp:39 [TRT]: To regenerate calibration cache, please delete the existing one. TensorRT will generate a new calibration cache.
INFO: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_func_utils.cpp:39 [TRT]: Some tactics do not have sufficient workspace memory to run. Increasing workspace size may increase performance, please check verbose output.
INFO: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_func_utils.cpp:39 [TRT]: Detected 1 inputs and 2 output network tensors.
ERROR: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_model_builder.cpp:1495 Serialize engine failed because of file path: /opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/samples/models/Primary_Detector/resnet10.caffemodel_b4_gpu0_int8.engine opened error
0:00:32.442386732 9829 0x5594636fc490 WARN nvinfer gstnvinfer.cpp:616:gst_nvinfer_logger:<primary_gie> NvDsInferContext[UID 1]: Warning from NvDsInferContextImpl::buildModel() <nvdsinfer_context_impl.cpp:1743> [UID = 1]: failed to serialize cude engine to file: /opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/samples/models/Primary_Detector/resnet10.caffemodel_b4_gpu0_int8.engine
WARNING: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_func_utils.cpp:36 [TRT]: Current optimization profile is: 0. Please ensure there are no enqueued operations pending in this context prior to switching profiles
INFO: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_model_builder.cpp:685 [Implicit Engine Info]: layers num: 3
0 INPUT kFLOAT input_1 3x368x640
1 OUTPUT kFLOAT conv2d_bbox 16x23x40
2 OUTPUT kFLOAT conv2d_cov/Sigmoid 4x23x40
```

```
0:00:32.447113083 9829 0x5594636fc490 INFO nvinfer gstnvinfer_impl.cpp:313:notifyLoadModelStatus:<primary_gie> [UID 1]: Load new model:/opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/samples/configs/deepstream-app/config_infer_primary.txt sucessfully
```

```
Runtime commands:
h: Print this help
q: Quit

p: Pause
r: Resume
NOTE: To expand a source in the 2D tiled display and view object details, left-click on the source.
To go back to the tiled display, right-click anywhere on the window.

**PERF: FPS 0 (Avg) FPS 1 (Avg) FPS 2 (Avg) FPS 3 (Avg)
**PERF: 0.00 (0.00) 0.00 (0.00) 0.00 (0.00) 0.00 (0.00)
** INFO: <bus_callback:181>: Pipeline ready

** INFO: <bus_callback:167>: Pipeline running

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

My nvidia driver and cuda version shown below:
[My nvidia driver and cuda version shown below:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8Ja0.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Maybe consider other forums too since it's not necessarily a coding question.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late with the answer.

> ERROR: …/nvdsinfer/nvdsinfer_model_builder.cpp:1523 Deserialize engine failed because file path: /opt/nvidia/deepstream/deepstream-5.0/samples/configs/deepstream-app/…/…/models/Primary_Detector/resnet10.caffemodel_b4_gpu0_int8.engine open error

The error message already give you the clue that is pointing to an engine file that does not exist on the path. Probably provide the full path to the engine file in the config file.